# Stored procedure works in SSMS but not in C# code

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns the record from the database matching the ID I pass into it.

But when I call that stored procedure from my ASP.NET Core 6 project, I don't get the results I should.

The C# code looks like this:

```
private List<HeaderModel> getHeaderNames(List<TagIDModel> allID)
{
    var allHeaders = new List<HeaderModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        var header = _context.Translation.FromSqlRaw("EXEC getHeader @key = {0}", allID[i].TagID).ToList();
        allHeaders.Add(new HeaderModel
                {
                    HeaderName = header[0].EnUs
                });
    }

    return removeDoubles(allHeaders);
}
```

In this case the `allID` collection has the following values:

```
1, 3 4, 6 & 7
```

They are passed one by one into the stored procedure which looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getHeader]
    @key int
AS
    SELECT Translation.id, [Key], [EN-US], [NL-NL], [CN-ZH]
    FROM Translation
    JOIN ParameterGroup ON Translation.id = ParameterGroup.ParameterGroupName
    JOIN TagData ON TagData.id=ParameterGroup.id
    WHERE TagData.id = @key
```

But the result only match half the time, yet they work perfectly in SSMS 2018.

The result from the stored procedure should be:

id: 5
Key: 7h48f
EN-US: Header-1

But instead I receive this:

id: 5
Key: jsoej
EN-US: Mixing

The ID is correct, but for an unknown reason the other values are incorrect.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I didnt realise they would show like that on the website, I apologise

Comment: How else did you think they would display? Did you think the site would take your image and transform it automatically into a markdown table or DDL and DML? If you paste an image, it's going to result in an image, not text.

Comment: Owh, I don't see the image (only a link). I thought you ment that was the problem (having to click the link to view the image)

Comment: No, the problem is the image. As the link states *"Please do not upload images of data"*; it doesn't state "Don't post links to images of data."

Comment: The question and it's tags don't give a clue what "_context.Translation.FromSqlRaw" represents. Is that an entity framework context, or something else? Perhaps consider adding a tag for that, and `sql-server`.

Comment: Since the data which is being returned from the query is not what you are expecting, my guess would be that your code isn't talking to the database that you think it is.

Comment: _context.Translation is just a generated model class based on the table "Translation" from the DB. The SP was working fine until I made some adjustments in my database. I did change most of the PK to "id" instead of idTranslation, idTagdata for instance. Could this result in miscommunication?